# MySQL make count not return anything if no rows are found

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to use a count in my MySQL query to count the amount of rows with a matching column, and the query is working, however when the select query the count is being used in returns no rows, the count value still returns 0 so the query will return an empty row except for the count column which has a 0.

This is my query:

```
SELECT
    forum_threads_forums.id,
    forum_threads.title,
    forum_threads.description,
    forum_threads.views,
    COUNT(DISTINCT forum_posts_threads.post_id) AS post_count,
    users.id AS user_id,
    users.username AS user_username
FROM
    forum_threads
INNER JOIN
    forum_threads_forums
ON
    forum_threads.id=forum_threads_forums.thread_id
AND
    forum_threads_forums.forum_id=:forum_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    forum_posts_threads
ON
    forum_posts_threads.thread_id=forum_threads_forums.thread_id
INNER JOIN
    users
ON
    forum_threads.user_id=users.id
```

When the select query doesn't return any rows, the count still does. So I get a result such as this:

```
id  title   description views   post_count  user_id user_username
                                0
```

I would like it to return nothing at all so I can then reliably count the results with PHP.

Does anyone have any idea on how to achieve this? I'm lost.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: did you forget to post the `group by` or do you not have one?

Comment: @gloomy.penguin I do not have one. Should I? The query works fine without it.

Comment: it depends what you're going for.  if you get the results you want now, then don't worry about it.  if you ever need a count per user or something, with more than one user in the result set, then you'll need to add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add:

```
HAVING post_count > 0
```

to the end of the query.

It will then return 1 row if there are any matches, and `post_count` will contain the number of distinct posts, or 0 rows if there were no matches.